# What is a clever bounding box for a 3D monte carlo integration?

Tags: computer-science, numerics

For a project, I need to calculate the overlap volume of two overlapping ellipsoids in 3D. The method itself isn't a problem: I'm basically picking random points within a bounding box and checking whether they're in both ellipsoids simultaneously.

In my never-ending quest to optimize the program in terms of runtime, a smaller bounding box would obviously be advantageous. Right now, the "box" is a sphere which is centered around the midpoint between the ellipsoids' centers of mass and has a diameter corresponding to the longest ellipsoid axis. This is completely arbitrary and I'm fairly certain the overlapping volume will always be contained in this sphere, but I'd really like to find some way to optimize the entire process.

Is there some general method to optimize the bounding volume?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a math problem, rather than a CS problem? What you seem to be asking for is a formula defining the possible overlap of two ellipsoids. You intend to use that formula to make your code more efficient, sure, but that is not related to the core question as far as I can tell. If you had the formula and were trying to figure out how to write it as code, that would be another story. Maybe you should consider posting this to https://math.stackexchange.com/

It seems to me you can redefine your question as "What is formula defining the volume where  overlap is possible between 2 ellipsoids in a 3D space?", and that has no reference to computing whatsoever.

Comment: I can't comment on jjrv's post due to rep, so I will comment on mine. Unfortunately his answer is wrong. examine the following image:http://wkp.maluke.com/en/img/Archimedes_sphere_and_cylinder.svg
Now, consider expanding the central sphere slightly. The edges of the outside shape would be violated, but the corners would not. This applies to cubes as well, I just couldn't find a picture for one

Comment: Lawton, can you elaborate on that? Once some of the cube's corners are inside and some are outside and you subdivide, can it fail?

Comment: @jjrv All of the cube's corners can be outside the sphere, and yet the sphere can have parts outside of the cube. Your suggestion makes the assumption that that is impossible, but it is not. It _is_ impossible with cubes inside of cubes, aligned on the same place, which is why the octree is useful. However, that assumption doesn't work if you rotate the cubes or use spheres, ellipses, or whatnot.

Comment: This image is a better explanation: http://eldar.mathstat.uoguelph.ca/dashlock/Outreach/POW/images/SquareCircle.jpg
As you can see, the circle _appears_ to be inside of the square, if you only examine the corners. However, that is incorrect, and the circle is actually not inside the square entirely.

Comment: What about an ellipse that was not centered in the square, and very thin but tall? Sorry I can't give a better description, but I think that would still fail.

Comment: Hmm you're right. So the algorithm needs to also detect intersections with a cube face and in those cases also subdivide the adjacent cube. Now I remember having done a similar thing before in 2D.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe more of a math than programming question but I'm thinking the intersection of 2 ellipsoids is a convex shape so maybe you could try another approach than Monte Carlo to deal with such a relatively nicely behaved object.

First you need to (somehow) find a point inside both ellipsoids.

Now create a cube centered at that point, large enough to completely contain both ellipsoids. Subdivide the cube along all 3 axes into 8 equally sized sub-cubes (first step of creating an octree).

After this, apply recursion to the subcubes. If some cube corners are inside both ellipsoids and some are not, subdivide the cube again. Also if some areas of cube faces are inside both ellipsoids and others not, subdivide again.

Repeat to desired recursion depth. You can track the calculation error by summing the volume of cubes that were subdivided.

Now the challenging operation here is resolving "if some areas of a cube face are inside both ellipsoids". An intersection between an ellipsoid and a plane is an ellipse. To inspect each of the 6 cube faces, you need to intersect them with the ellipsoids and then intersect the remaining ellipses with each other if they both overlap the cube face. Luckily for 2D ellipse-ellipse overlap test you can find references more easily...

Monte Carlo will give you n bits of accuracy with O(2^n) effort so for example 24 bits takes  16.7 million samples. If you focus on the shape surface with such a divide and conquer method, you should only need O(2^(n*2/3)) samples which is about 65 thousand for 24 bits.

Also your concern about initial bounding box size becomes irrelevant since excess is quickly  removed in initial recursion steps.

Comment: This is a nice approach.  I think it won't scale well in higher dimensions, though.  (I'm pretty sure you knew that; I just wanted to make it more explicit for the original poster.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea if you want to stick to Monte Carlo:

Project your ellipsoids on the XZ plane to get 2 ellipses. Calculate the intersection of their bounding rectangles to use as a bounding rectangle for your calculations.

Then shoot rays through the XZ plane within your bounding rectangle, along the Y axis. For each ray, calculate intersections with the ellipsoids and calculate the length of the ray that is inside both. Add this to a variable "hits_length".

The volume of the ellipsoid intersection should be approximated by:

hits_length / rays_shot * bounding_rectangle_area

Again this way you're calculating the volume by sampling a 2D space which should make it converge faster.